# MailChimp Unsubscribe/Resubscribe from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

We have an admin page in Ruby on Rails which is integrated to MailChimp(using gibbon gem). I could successfully unsubscribe & resubscribe members of the list. But if a user unsubscribe using MailChimp footer merge tag in the newsletter, it is not allowing to resubscribe using this admin page. I figured that a reconfirmation email has to be sent before the user can be added to the list. 
I am looking for a way to identify if the user has been unsubscribed manually (by admin) or the user itself, and the page will have resubscribe or resend confirmation accordingly in RoR webpage.

I am using the below syntax to retrieve the members:
response = gibbon.list("xxxxxx").members.retrieve

And I can't find a particular tag in response.body to show if this has been unsubscribed manually(admin) or by the user.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has been unsubscribed, it's not possible to resubscribe them directly via the API, but you can force an opt-in email to go out to them again by setting their status to 'pending'. One way to do this is to use upsert:

```
gibbon.lists('xxxx').members('email_md5_hash').upsert(body: {status: 'pending'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try and get back on the results. Is there a way to identify if the member has been unsubscribed by an admin and or by the member itself. I would like to show that in the RoR admin page (via api), so that the admin can either resubscribe and make a call to this upsert statement to send an email.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to tell who initiated the unsubscribe.

Comment: Okay, and the upsert worked to initiate an email. Thanks for your help.